# When I refresh the page my const size is different

Tags: javascript

I am creating a javascript carousel slider. In doing so, if I let the browser sit for a while, it correctly records the width of my img that I am sliding.  If I hit refresh, my const size returns 0.   I then have to let my browser sit for a minute or so. Then I can refresh and it works properly again. I'm using live server visual code if that makes a difference.

```
 const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

//Buttons

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//counter 

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(size);

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)'; 

//button listeners

nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform =  'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});
```

Comment: @tadman The author states that the name of the variable is `size`.

Comment: @flamesdev Ah, `const size` not `const` size.

Comment: Are you running this code after the document has become "ready" or are you jumping the gun and running it before any of the DOM has had a chance to settle?

Comment: @tadman the script is just before the end of my body in my html.

Comment: Javascript variables aren't preserved between page refreshes.

Comment: @andray right.  But the variable should be the same with each refresh. Why would it change to 0 when I refresh? The img is the same width in the browser, however clientWidth() returns 0

Comment: This calls for some debugging, and specifically, to verify that you actually have the elements you think you have on the page at the time you think you have them. If they AJAX load in a moment later this code won't be sequenced correctly.